# How can I use turtle graphics in maxscript to align the bent boxes

Tags: turtle-graphics, 3dsmax, maxscript

```
struct Turtle (

    position_ = [0, 0, 0], 
    heading_= [0, 1, 0], 
    rotationQuat_ = quat 0 0 0 1,
    amount = 200,
    turnAngle = 45,

    fn forward = (      
        c = box pos: position_ wirecolor: red width: 40 length: amount height: 2 lengthSegs: 10
        rotate c rotationQuat_
        position_ = position_ + amount * heading_
    ),
    fn left = (
        q = quat -turnAngle [0, 0, 1]
        rotationQuat_ = q * rotationQuat_
        invq = inverse q           
        heading_ = heading_ * invq  

        c = box pos: position_ wirecolor: red width: 40 length: amount height: 2 lengthSegs: 10
        addmodifier c (bend())
        c.bend.bendAngle = 45
        c.bend.bendAxis = 1     
            
        rotate c rotationQuat_
        position_ = position_ + amount * heading_
    ),
    fn right = (
        q = quat turnAngle [0, 0, 1] 
        rotationQuat_ = q * rotationQuat_ 
        invq = inverse q               
        heading_ = heading_ * invq  

        c = box pos: position_ wirecolor: red width: 40 length: amount height: 2 lengthSegs: 10
        addmodifier c (bend())
        c.bend.bendangle = -45
        c.bend.bendAxis = 1
            
        rotate c rotationQuat_
        position_ = position_ + amount * heading_
    )
)

fn main = (
    delete objects
    
    t = Turtle()

    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.left()
    t.right()
    t.forward()
    t.forward()
    t.right()
    
)

main()
```

I'm trying to create a path using turtle graphics but because the boxes don't line up properly once you bend it I can't get them align. I managed to get it temporarily working by changing the pivot point on each shape but it was hard coded so that only worked in certain scenarios. How can I get each of the boxes to align?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make use of the fact that pivot of a box is at zero in local Z, and switch the orientation of both the box and the bend gizmo so that it bends around its base and not around the center. Since you're bending the box, you also cannot simply move by the box lenght but you have to calculate an offset along the bent arc instead. All in all, this is how I'd do that:

```
struct Turtle
(
    private transform = arbAxis y_axis,
    public stepLength = 200,
    public turnAngle = 45,

    private fn updateTransform angle distance =
        if angle == 0 then transform *= transMatrix (transform.row3 * distance)
        else transform = rotateYMatrix angle * transMatrix (distance / degToRad angle * [1 - cos angle, 0, sin angle]) * transform,

    private fn stride distance bendAngle =
    (
        local stripe = Box width:40 length:2 height:stepLength widthSegs:1 lengthSegs:1 heightSegs:10 transform:transform wirecolor:red
        if bendAngle != 0 do addModifier stripe (Bend bendAxis:2 bendAngle:bendAngle)
        updateTransform bendAngle distance
    ),
    
    public fn forward = stride stepLength 0,
    public fn left = stride stepLength turnAngle,
    public fn right = stride stepLength -turnAngle
)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but say I want to put something on the outside/inside of the shape how would I go about changing the code? If the object I'm adding has a relative location to the shape. And can you explain the matrix  math you did in the updateTransform() function?

Comment: You can do it the same way how the boxes are placed - but stated like this it's a different question that would could just as well have a different answer - and you yourslef mention a 'shape' which is not what the bent boxes really are (IMHO you'd be better off making a guiding line instead). The matrix math is 1) rotate by the increment, 2) offset along the arc (distance / the angle in radians gives you the radius of the arc, cos and sin give you the point on unit circle that you shift one unit along x (you're already on the arc), hence 1 minus that), 3) mutliply by the last transform.